# Automate clickOnce deployment with NAnt

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, clickonce, nant

Currently I have a `WPF` application that is deployed via `clickOnce` deployment in `VisualStudio`.

I want to include this deployment in `NAnt`.

I have followed this blogpost:
http://weblogs.asp.net/joewrobel/archive/2013/02/06/automating-clickonce-deployment.aspx

With it I have managed to automate deployment of files, manifest, app signing and zipping the deployment.

One thing I am missing is making setup.exe.

In VisualStudio this is done in: `"project properties/publish/prerequisites"`

[image]

Can someone help me putting this action in my `NAnt` build script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install `NAntContrib` (in case you haven't already done it). It contains the task `msbuild`. As its name already says, it uses msbuild to build your project. To make sure msbuild creates your setup file as well, you need to set the switch `target` to `publish`.

You would need to use it to build your projects instead of the target `csc` or `solution` or whatever you were using. That's because you can add any arguments you want to the `msbuild` task which is not possible in the others.

In NAnt, this would look something like this:

```
<msbuild project="D:\Projects\ProjectName.sln">
  <arg value="/target:publish" />
</msbuild>
```

This should create a folder called "app.publish" in your output path containing the setup file.

[NAntContrib](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/) (The download contains install instructions)

[Building ClickOnce Applications from the Command Line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms165431.aspx)